# What is a mechanical cue?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, cell-biology, cell-signaling

I was attending a talk related to neurogenesis. So one professor was asking a question related to biochemical cues and mechanical cues (related to signaling pathways I believe). Cue as far as I understand is a signal, right? Biochemical cue is understandable for me.

*But what does mechanical cue mean?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mechanical pressure, stress, strain or [distortion](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19186141) are mechanical cues. In general, cues sensed by [mechanoreceptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanoreceptor) are mechanical cues!

Comment: It is not necessary that mechanical cues are sensed by mechanoreceptors. These cues can also be relayed via the cytoskeleton and the adhesion proteins.

Comment: I doubt adhesion proteins can transduce mechanical signal. They can only recognize specific molecule or protein on opposite cell (or ECM). They are sending chemical signals not mechanical.

Comment: Adhesion proteins relay the mechanical stress as they are directly connected to the cytoskeleton. They are not really like signalling receptors. See [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25933372) abstract:  *"Experimental evidence confirms that cell differentiation or proliferation can be regulated according to the extracellular matrix stiffness..."*. So adhesion proteins are involved in relaying these signals.

Comment: In given paper, there is no clear indication of any adhesion protein. Given study is mathematical model with correlations. However I found this line in that paper's conclusion, "_α5β1-integrin could switch between relaxed and tensioned states in response to traction forces generated by a cell._". This gave me [this](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/323/5914/642) reference. Which suggest that 'a5b1' is 'most likely' candidate who changes confirmation by mechanical stress. In that case 'a5b1' will be mechanoreceptor by definition :P

Comment: Well they are not classified as mechanoreceptors, if you are getting what I am trying to say. I am not refuting what you are saying, but you cannot call integrins as mechanoreceptors. This is just like the equilibrium- steady state argument. It is a matter of classification and not an all pervasive superlogic :P